# Getting text from html page, shell

Tags: shell

I am trying to get text from a html page in shell, as part of a script to show me the temperature in my local area.

I however can't get my head around how to use grep properly

Excerpt from web page

```
</div><div id="yw-forecast" class="night" style="height:auto"><em>Current conditions as of 8:18 PM GMT</em><div id="yw-cond">Light Rain Shower</div><dl><dt>Feels Like:</dt><dd>6 &deg;C</dd><dt>Barometer:</dt><dd style="position:relative;">1,015.92 mb and steady</dd><dt>Humidity:</dt><dd>87 %</dd><dt>Visibility:</dt><dd>9.99 km</dd><dt>Dewpoint
```

Except shorter cut down further

```
<dt>Feels Like:</dt><dd>6 &deg;C</dd>
```

Trying to grab the 6 °C

I have tried a variety of different tactics, including grep and awk. Can a shell wizard help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
grep -o -e "<dd>.*deg;C</dd>" the_html.txt
```

From the man page:

```
-e PATTERN, --regexp=PATTERN
      Use PATTERN as  the  pattern.   This  can  be  used  to  specify
      multiple search patterns, or to protect a pattern beginning with
      a hyphen (-).  (-e is specified by POSIX.)

...

-o, --only-matching
      Print only the matched (non-empty) parts  of  a  matching  line,
      with each such part on a separate output line.
```

---

If you want to get rid of `<dd>` and `</dd>` too, just append `| cut -b 5-12`.

Comment: $ grep -o -e "<dd>[^<]*deg;C</dd>" /tmp/weather.html 

$ <dd>6 &deg;C</dd>

Comment: Right. Updated the answer to include how to get rid of those dd-tags.

Comment: Thanks, this problem has been driving me crazy!

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
grep -Po '(?<=Feels Like:</dt><dd>).*?(?=</dd>)' | sed 's/ &deg;/°/'
```

Result:

```
6°C
```

Comment: Nice idea, I was thinking about lookarounds, but read that it wasn't implemented in `grep`... `-P` does the trick :-)

Answer (score 0):

If x is your input file and the HTML source is as regularly formatted as your write, this should work --

grep deg x | sed -e "s#^.*>([0-9]{1,2} \°[CF])<.*#\1#"

Seth